# Need to change the background color of the templates(Widgets) in flutter_carplay

Tags: flutter, carplay

[I am using this flutter package to achieve carplay in IOS.](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carplay)

But the package has the default color of widgets as  skyblue(Flutter's color) and I couldn't find any parameter to change the color. Please help me to change the color to pink. Thanks.

[image]